# Возможно ли создать динамическую пагинацию на Django?

Tags: python, django, пагинация

На странице https://danretail.ru/ в разделе “Блог” установлена пагинация на 12. В шаблон передается список объектов, в которых присутствуют и новости, и статьи. Дизайн состоит в том, что одна статья занимает место трех новостей (то есть три блока), и идет чередование: сначала статья, потом три новости и т.д.  Задача моя стояла в том, чтобы после того, как закончатся статьи, я обычными мелкими блоками новостей заполнял остаток страницы. Но вот тут как раз появилась проблема: на второй странице https://danretail.ru/blog/?page=2 появляются в конце пустые места, если на странице одна или две статьи. Пытался найти решение проблемы, но не смог. Я думал на динамической пагинацией в Django, которая бы для каждой страницы зависела от количества определенных объектов, но информации и возможности как её реализовать не нашел. Может кто посоветовать решение проблемы? Или может здесь бэк вообще не причем будет для решения проблемы и нужно просто изменить дизайн?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что новости и статьи лежат в одном списке и режутся пагинатором по 12? Что-то мне подсказывает, что их надо передавать разными списками и резать разными пагинаторами. Статей брать, допустим по 3, а новостей по 9.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров да, именно так. Они лежат в одном списке. Несколько пагинаторов могут быть в одном контроллере-классе, или же стоит разбить на два контроллера?

Comment: ну 2 пагинатора в принципе могут быть в одном контроллере, почему бы и нет) Попробуйте.

Comment: как вариант, вы можете взять все элементы со страницы из пагинатора, разделить их на 2 списка, а потом уже выводить

Comment: либо отсортировать перед выводом. естественно все это делается в контексте . если ответ подойдет - офорлю как нормальный ответ